# Showing and hiding controls from both controller and view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a best possible solution for this but as this is the first time I am encountering this scenario so I am not sure how to best implement this.

I have a very simple model,

```
public class Feedback
{       
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Current ID")]
public int? PreviousID { get; set; }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "Next ID")]
public int? NextID { get; set; }

[Required]
public int ScenarioID { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Select you scenario")]
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> YourScenario { get; set; }
```

}

When User first loads the view then only dropdownlist for YourScenario and TextBox for PreviousID is displayed. When User select dropdownlist then based on its value the TextBox for NextID is displayed to user. Here is my view,

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.YourScenario, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ScenarioID, m.YourScenario, "Choose Scenario", new { @class = "form-control chosen-select" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PreviousID, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
   <div class="col-sm-9">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PreviousID)
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" style="display:none">
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NextID, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
   <div class="col-sm-9">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NextID)
   </div>
</div>
```

To show/hide the NextID I use the Jquery on the view,

```
   $('#YourScenario').change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        var nextID = $('#NextID');

        if (selectedValue = "3") {
            nextID .show();
        }
        else {
            nextID .hide();
        }
    });
```

All this works great. Now to use the same View as Edit Mode I pass the model to the view from controller. What I want is that the TextBox for NextID should be displayed or hidden automatically based on the model values. If I use if condition on the View then the control is not available through Javascript so how can I achieve this?

Comment: what about writing the logic in document.ready?

Comment: You can simply fire the change event in the final of your javascript code.
If you're in "New" mode, there isn't value, so the visible fields will be the same, but int the "Edit" mode, as the field has value, it will show the necessary fields. Something like this:
$('#YourScenario').trigger('change');

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual Are you suggesting to write this logic in the document.ready? When the page loads I write the logic to show and hide the controls? Instead of showing and hide through jquery I was also thinking to pass the model to the controller and return the model again to view with if conditions but I am not sure about it because it seems like extra time to send the value to controller even with Ajax. I was just hoping that somehow the if statement and jquery show/hide get work together.

Comment: Yes, the last line in document.ready, but you will just add this line to your actual and working code. Your code will remain the same, just adding this line to fire the change event and use the function you wrote, so when the model is "empty", nothing will happen, but when you have a value, it can show/hide properly

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual I hope that I am not asking too much but if you could post your comments as answer with some sample code (change function) then I will accept it as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example:  https://jsfiddle.net/jma71jf7/

When you run the code, it will hide the input, because there is no selected value, and this line will trigger the change event function:

```
$('#YourScenario').trigger('change');
```

But when editing, the select will have some value, and it will hide/show the input according to the value.

Comment: Thanks I got it. Just one quick thing. Is it possible to access Model values in JQuery? Jut wondering?

Comment: Yes Adnan, you can access the fields you bind (like NextId) and if there's a value you didn't bind to any field, or a session/viewbag value you want to access, you must to assign to a javascript variable, like this:
<script type='text/javascript'>
var userId = '@(Model.UserId)';
</script>
or instead in a hidden field:
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)